# Android: Null object reference error on adding exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to stream a video and show the subtitles in an app. 
I have the following methods:

```
 private void initializePlayer() {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.mp4");
    //subtitle http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.srt
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
            createMediaSource(uri);
}
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void hideSystemUi() {
    playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}

 private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
```

and I am calling them as follows:

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUi();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error on starting my app:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.appcompat.app.WindowDecorActionBar.doHide(WindowDecorActionBar.java:842)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.WindowDecorActionBar.updateVisibility(WindowDecorActionBar.java:782)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.WindowDecorActionBar.hideForSystem(WindowDecorActionBar.java:725)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:244)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setActionBarVisibilityCallback(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:174)
```

The error seems to be related to the actionbar but I am not using it nor I am changing its alpha. Why is this happening? Please help

upadte:
added ui xml and buildMediaSource issue

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also while adding the subtitles I am having trouble merging the media source of the video and the subtitle:

```
 private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
      MediaSource mediaSource =  new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab")).
                createMediaSource(uri);
        if((srt_link==null|| srt_link.equals("false") || srt_link.isEmpty())){

            return mediaSource;
        }
        Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP,
                Format.NO_VALUE,"hi");

        Uri uriSubtitle = Uri.parse(srt_link);
        MediaSource subtitleSource =new SingleSampleMediaSource(uriSubtitle, new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video"), textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);

        MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);

        return mergedSource;


    }
```

SingleSampleMediaSource is deprecated. How do I merge the two.

Comment: maybe post the xmls of your layout so that we can check them too?

Comment: see the xml it is simple. and also help me merge the mediasources of the video and the subtitle.

Comment: hey I solved the first issue help with the deprecated SingleSampleMediaSource method